# Liste von adjektivisch verwendeten Partizipien nicht mehr verwendeter Infinitive

Tags: online-resource, participle, big-list

*Aufgedunsen* ist gebildet aus dem nicht mehr gebräuchlichen starken Verb *aufdinsen* (<sup>23</sup>Kluge, 63).

*Auserkoren* wäre vielleicht ein weiterer Kandidat, wobei *auserkiesen* noch nicht völlig verschwunden ist. Aber: *Ich erkiese aus* (oder: *Ich auserkiese*?) wäre heute sehr ungewöhnlich.

Gibt es eine Liste gebräuchlicher Partizipformen, bei denen der Infinitiv oder andere Deklinationen nicht mehr verwendet werden?

Comment: Die beiden Wörter *"aufgedunsen"* und *"auserkoren"* sind keine Adjektive, sondern  Partizipien. Wenn ein Wort wie ein Adjektiv verwendet werden kann, aber von einem Verb abgeleitet ist, ist es immer ein Partizip. Genau das definiert ja ein Partizip. Ein Partizip nimmt immer eine Zwitterstellung zwischen Verb und Adjektiv ein. Beispiel: *"Lisa hat ihr Zimmer aufgeräumt." - "Das Zimmer sieht aufgeräumt aus."* Im ersten Satz kommt das Verbhafte von *aufgeräumt"* zum Vorschein, im zweiten das Adjektivische. Oder auch: *"Kurt hat Ernst zu seinem Nachfolger auserkoren"* = verbhafte Verwendung.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast *Das ist verrückt.* Adjektiv oder Partizip?

Comment: @DavidVogt kommt auf den Kontext an ;)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ja, *Adjektiv* ist der falsche Ausdruck. Ich hatte erst Partizip II geschrieben, aber zu fragen, welche Verben es gibt, die heute verwendet werden aber heute nicht mehr verwendet werden (denn auserkiesen und auserkoren sind ja ein Verb) erschien mir wenig sinnvoll. Ich präzisiere die Frage.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Wenn das Wort *"verrückt"* im übertragenen Sinn verwendet wird und daher die Herkunft vom Verb keine Rolle mehr spielt, ist es ein Adjektiv, sonst aber ein Partizip. Beispiel 1: *"Irgendetwas ist hier anders als noch gestern, vor der Party. Ja, das Sofa! **Das ist verrückt.** Komm hilf mir, es wieder an seinen angestammten Platz zu rücken."* Beispiel 2: In meiner Geburtsstadt Graz wurden 2012 mehrere Ortstafeln verrückt. *"In Graz müssen zahlreiche Ortstafeln verrückt werden. "* [steiermark.orf.at](https://steiermark.orf.at/v2/news/stories/2546818/) ...

Comment: ... Den Unterschied zwischen Adjektiv und Partizip sieht man besser im Perfekt. Adjektiv: *"Heinz ist **verrückt geworden.**"* Aber Partizip: *"Das Sofa ist **verrückt worden.**"*

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, gute Beobachtung.

Comment: Ich schmeiße mal _gedungen_ in die Runde. Aber eine Liste wäre recht iteressant!

Comment: @phipsgabler Das Verb *dingen* ist schon noch in Gebrauch (aber das ist *auserkiesen* ja irgendwie auch).

Comment: Paar Beispiele: bescheiden, unverhohlen, verschroben, verschollen.
Mein alter Prof hat sie "extraparadigmatische Archaismen" genannt. Ich weiß nicht, wohin dich die Suche danach führen wird, oder ob das irgendwelche Treffer liefert bei Google oder ähnlichem. 
Interessant: "verwunschen" ist eine poetische Bildung zu "wünschen", und wünschen war nie ein starkes Verb.

Comment: @Philipp naja, zumindest beinahe so antiquiert, finde ich. Ich glaube nicht, dass es außerhalb von fixen Wendungen vorkommt, und diese werden zu 99 % aus eben dem Partizip bestehen (vgl. [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dingen_V%2C+gedungen_ADJ&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgedungen_ADJ%3B%2Cc0). Aber wenn man sich gebildet genug vorkommt kann man ja alles mögliche spaßhalber doch verwenden -- dessen bekenne ich mich auch völlig schuldig :) (Insbesondere verwende ich _bescheiden_ sehr gern als finites Verb!)

Comment: @Ledda Warum keine offizielle Antwort?

Answer (score 1):

Ich hab da ggf. eine Quelle gefunden, die mit alten Wörtern prüfbar auf deren aktuelle Verwendung ist.

Spontan beim browsen gefunden:

Das Verb „ängsten“ wird nicht mehr verwendet, aber „verängstigt“.

Andere Verben von dort: abarten, kleinen

Siehe [Früh-neuhochdeutsches Wörterbuch](https://fwb-online.de/lemma/%C3%A4ngsten.s.3v)

Dann hat mir ein netter Mensch noch folgendes gegeben:

Die Rote Liste für vom Aussterben bedrohte Verben https://neutsch.org/Rote_Liste

Die schwarze Liste für ausgestorbene Verben. https://neutsch.org/Schwarze_Liste

Comment: Ich bin kein Sprachhistorie-Interessent im engeren Sinn, daher mag das mit sich bringen, dass ich diesem schönen Wörterbuch auch mit der Erklärung unter https://fwb-online.de/content/hinweise-zur-benutzung-des-woerterbuchs oder https://fwb-online.de/einleitung/positionen-des-woerterbuchartikels-i-das-lemma keine Angabe zu "wird noch verwendet ja/nein" entlocken kann. Wäre es hilfreich, das am verlinkten "ängsten" eben zu zitieren und aufzuzeigen?

Comment: Dass du glaubst, das Verb *ängstigen* würde nicht mehr verwendet, ängstigt mich. Es wird gegenwärtig (stand 2019) etwas häufiger verwendet als *schlürfen, schälen* und *zücken*, aber etwas seltener als *wühlen, spitzen* und *bücken*. Innerhalb der letzten 15Jahre hat sich die Frequenz von "ängstigen* sogar verdoppelt.

Comment: Quelle der obigen Behauptung: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=31&smoothing=3&content=ängstigt%2Cschlürft%2Cbückt%2Czückt%2Cspitzt%2Cschält%2Cwühlt&year_end=2019&year_start=1900&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cängstigt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cschlürft%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbückt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Czückt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspitzt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cschält%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwühlt%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cängstigt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cschlürft%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbückt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Czückt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspitzt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cschält%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwühlt%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @HubertSchölnast ich schrieb auch nicht "ängstigen" sondern "ängsten" (Verbum). Du selbst schreibst ja auch nicht gerade "ich ängste mich".

Comment: @Walter: Ok, das hatte ich überlesen, aber in diesem Fall vergleichst du Äpfel mit Birnen. Das Wort *»verängstigt«* ist das Partizip II von *»verängstigen«* (siehe [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/verängstigen)). Dieses Wort wiederum entsteht aus *»ängstigen«* indem man das Präfix *ver-* voranstellt. Das Partizip II von *»ängsten«* wird vermutlich *»geängstet«* sein (ich vermute das weil *kosten, leisten, testen, trösten, rüsten, listen, lasten, tasten, husten* usw. ihr Partizip nach diesem Muster bilden).

Comment: Is klar, ob *ängsten* überhaupt ein echtes Wort ist? Der Versuch müsste schwierig sein, es abzugrenzen von PG \*ankon- "to complain" (cf. Kroonen 2013, unterstellt sekundäres \*k am Beispiel OE "stalk, steal", für IG \*h3enh3- mit Hettitisch *hannai ~ hannanzi* "to sue, judge" etc. Während *Angst* zufällig mit Lat. *ango* quasi bei *eng* steht, ähnlich *nahe, narrow*, Vgl. dagegen etwa Kölsch *Angks*, ferner *anklagen, Anklage stellen*), sodass *ängsten* eventuel nur als analogische Rückbildung erscheint und so vielleicht nie Grundlage für *ängstigen* war. Stellt euch mal nicht so ang.

Comment: Auf dieser schwarzen Liste stehen *bewiffene* Beispiele, sehr schön. Allerdings ist z.B. *tweren* "rühren" relativ offensichtlich (also ohne Gewähr) verwandt mit *quirlen*, insofern mit *quer* ein Ur-Indo-Germanisches \*terk^(w)- unterstellt wird--was aber selbst fraglich ist. So sind einige dieser Wort vermutlich dialektalisch, die einfach nicht wirklich in der Standardsprache akzeptiert wurden, also auch nie daraus verschwunden sein konnten, bzw. ja noch bestehen, nur in anderer Form. *spurnen* ist noch in *anspornen*, *sachen* ist lebendig, *was du nich sachst [sagtst]*, ...

Comment: ... *rimpfen* ist *Nase rümpfen*, *lingen* ist seit jeher *gelingen*, AHD *gilingan*, zwar MND und Allemanisch *lingen*, so bemerkt Grimm es auch in MHD, doch es ist wohl bekannt das *g-* zuerst in Nord-Deutsch schwand (proxy s. En. *enough* "genug", *like, alike* "gleich", *luck* "Glück", dagegen Hoch Deutsch *es langt*, sowie *das klingt gut*, Herkunft dunkel), *klieben* "spalten" ist noch itterativ in *klappen*, bzw. *klaffen*, bzw. in *kniepen, kneifen* (vgl clover, knoblauch), *kleiben* "anhaften" ist offensichtlich *kleben*, *kellen, killen* "frieren" ist noch transitiv in *kühlen*, …